# postgresql - better to have an integer column to track count, or just use count(*)?

Tags: postgresql

So I have one table, let's call it `posts`, that has a column `num_likes`, which is a type integer, and it's used to track the number of likes. I have another table, called `post_likes`, which is used to track which user liked which post: so it's a many-to-many relationship between two columns, `user_id` and `post_id`. My question is, is it better to get the number of likes with the column that I am incrementing or decrementing every time with `UPDATE SET`, or to just run `COUNT(*)`?

Comment: [This page](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-count-function/) goes over your issue in some detail.

Comment: It's better to use `count(*)` rather than storing that information and may be extract that from a View whenever needed.